# Shader warning in 'Master': implicit truncation of vector type

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I get these warnings whenever I save changes in any shader file.
It does not seem to relate directly to the shader files, since it works perfectly in a new project.
Unfortunately it seems impossible to open this "Master" shader and edit it, double clicking the error message does not open any file.

[image: Master shader error]

I'm using Unity 2021.1.0b11.2079 and the Universal Render Pipeline.

Does anyone know why these warnings appear and how I can solve the root issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is a shader you created yourself? Master sounds like Shadergraph. The error says that you truncate some values (cut off everything after the floating points), that does not necessarily mean you get a wrong value but could lead to errors. Without further informations it's hard to say what exactly you are doing and where the errors reside

Comment: No, 'Master' is not a shader I created myself. I cannot find the file either, it looks like it's something from Unity itself, since I cannot open it.

Comment: I actually also get the warnings for some URP shaders like 'Universal Render Pipeline/Terrain/Lit'. It's really weird.

Comment: For me this error popped up when I imported a shader that was made in a much older version: do you have some old code somewhere, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The warning just means that some components of the vector are being ignored as it is converted to another type with less components(for example float3 to float2). In a script(here HLSL), instead of writing

```
float3 a = float3(1, 2, 3);
float2 b = a;
```

(which will give your a warning) you can simply write

```
float3 a = float3(1, 2, 3);
float2 b = a.xy;
```

The behaviour is the same, but the warning is gone.